# Splitting a column into 2 in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a date column which was programmed a long time ago as a (`numeric(17,9), not null`) data type (e.g. 20130623.1434480600). I am only interested in the data for the day before the current day and UserCode=Automation as the reports that will be sent out will only consist of those results done automatically 1 day before. I have converted it into a `DateTime` function (`6/23/2013 10:34:48`) with the following query along with a specific user requirements:

This displays under the `Date` column: `2013-06-23 16:54:56.993`

I have come up with this query but it is giving me some errors:

```
    SELECT 
    CAST (DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([DATE],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([DATE],15,3))) AS TIME,8) 'Time',
    [Object] AS [Dataset],
    SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
    FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
    [Object],
    MsgID,
    Parms
    FROM JnlDataSection
    WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME))) A
    Where MsgID = '325' AND
    SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' 
    Order By Date DESC;
```

### ERRORS:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.
REQUIRED OUTPUT:

- First Column: Date: `2013-06-23`
- Second Column: Time: `16:54`

Can anyone make any suggestions to my current code as to how I would get the required output?

That would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can cast as DATE and TIME separately:

```
SELECT CAST('6/23/2013 10:34:48' AS DATE), CAST('6/23/2013 10:34:48' AS TIME)
```

So for your example:

```
SELECT  ItemId,
 CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
            SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'DateOnly',
 LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
            SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
            SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'TimeOnly',
 [Object],
 SourceSite,
 DestSite
 FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
    [Object],
    SourceSite,
    DestSite,
                UserCode
 FROM JnlMediumMove
 WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
 CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove   the time part
 WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
 ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: it is giving me this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'Date'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: Alright this is working fine, and one more question how would I remove the seconds and microseconds from the Time?

Comment: of course it would be better to refactor your database to start using datae and time as separate fields with the date and time datatypes. This type of conversion in select queries is expensive.

Comment: @HLGEM One last question.  Is it possible to edit the query to show the entire database isntead of one day prior?

Comment: @GoatCo Is it possible to edit the query that's in my question right now? I don't want just yesterdays date I want the entire database and it's giving me some errors.

Comment: You're unlikely to get new answers to old questions by unchecking an accepted answer.